# Continuously changing Express Route Paths for protection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, encryption

I want to create a hidden internal webserver with ever-changing routes.

The aim is to prevent/deter people from scraping the site or using the API without permission.

There's probably a better way (or this could be totally useless)

I've written some code that works but either convince me why I'm wasting my time or why it would work.

```
const express = require('express');
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

const app = express();

// These are the hidden routes
const routes = {
    hiddenPage: undefined,
};

setInterval(() => {
    // Change the path of the hidden page 
    // every 5 seconds
    routes.hiddenPage = `/${uuid()}`;
}, 1000 * 5);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    // There would be other middleware for 
    // security reasons 

    if (req.path === routes.hiddenPage) {
        res.send('Welcome to the hidden page');
        return;
    }

    res.send(`Page at <a href=${routes.hiddenPage}>${routes.hiddenPage}</a>`);
});

// Listen on 3000
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: `The aim is to prevent/deter people from scraping the site or using the API without permission.` The standard approach for this is to use authentication. A well established and well supported way of preventing API abuse. Regarding your code, how would the client know which URL to request...?

Comment: This is more for front end rather than the API. And is just for more protection.

The urls get sent to the client
`res.send(`Page at <a href=${routes.hiddenPage}>${routes.hiddenPage}</a>`);`

Comment: So once you get the endpoint, you can always get the next endpoint, and keep using the api without permission?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CORS middleware to allow only specific clients to access your server.
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Example:

```js
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com',
}

app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```